# How to add toolbar button to contact item window in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an add-in for Outlook. One requirement is to add a toolbar button to the contact item window. Can anyone tell me how to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using VSTO to develop the plugin?

Comment: yes, i do (spam spam spam spam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what Outlook versions you want to support you have to use two approaches.

On **Outlook < 2007** you either add a new commandbar via `myInspector.CommandBars.Add("my commandbar")` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432801.aspx)) or use an existing one via e.g. `myInspector.CommandBars.Item(1)` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa433023.aspx)).
Then add a button via `myCommandBar.Controls.Add()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432790.aspx)).

On **Outlook >= 2007** you need to customize the ribbon which is a bit more writing work. [Customizing the Ribbon in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226712.aspx) is a good introduction into that.